# webpack Failed to load resource using outputPath in assets/resource

Tags: url, webpack, path, assets, public

I'm not very familiar with webpack.

My goal was to put all the assets inside my HTML in a specific folder.
For that, I set a new option under the rule that deals with the `type: assets/resource:

```js
{
  test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|png|jpg|gif)$/i,
  type: 'asset/resource',
  generator: {
    outputPath: 'assets/' // this is the new option setted
  }
}
```

It does actually work. webpack creates the folder after compiling and brings those files inside it. The problem is that the HTML file compiled doesn't understand that the assets files are inside `assets/` folder.

How can I fix it?

Here is my `webpack.config.js`

```js
const path = require('path')
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin')
const ImageMinimizerPlugin = require('image-minimizer-webpack-plugin')

const stylesHandler = MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader


const base = {
    entry: {
        bundle: [
            './js/main.js',
            './css/style.scss'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'docs')
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'index.html',
            scriptLoading: 'module',
            inject: 'body'
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [stylesHandler, 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|png|jpg|gif)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
                generator: {
                    outputPath: 'assets/' // this is the new option setted
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/i,
                use: ['html-loader']
            }
        ]
    }
}

const dev = {
    devServer: {
        open: false,
        host: 'localhost',
        watchFiles: ['./index.html']
    }
}

const prod = {
    output: {
        clean: true
    }
}


module.exports = (env, args) => {
    switch (args.mode) {
        case 'development':
            return merge(base, dev)
        case 'production':
            return merge(base, prod)
        default:
            throw new Error('No matching configuration was found!')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I discover it by myself, and it was kinda obvious.

Well, when webpack compiles your `index.html` file, it won't understand if you just give a new path for your assets final destiny.

For example, like I did:

```js
{
  test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|png|jpg|gif)$/i,
  type: 'asset/resource',
  generator: {
    outputPath: 'assets/' // this is the new option set
  }
}
```

In order this to work you need to specify the `publicPath`:

```js
{
  test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|png|jpg|gif)$/i,
  type: 'asset/resource',
  generator: {
    outputPath: 'assets/' // this is the new option set
    publicPath: 'assets/'
  }
}
```

You're telling webpack:

1. Put all the assets inside `outputPath`.
2. Hey HTML, when you look for the assets, please include the `publicPath` before looking for it.